# How to change font color of unselected Chakra UI tabs?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

**I've been searching this for a while now and have no clue yet how to change the font color of the unselected Chakra UI tabs.**

I've Light and dark mode. The tabs show fine on light mode as can see below

[image]

But, for dark mode the font color of unselected tab is barely visible as below
[image]

So, I want to change the font color of this unselected tab in Chakra UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Style props + custom component**

```
const unselectedColor = useColorModeValue(unselectedColorLightTheme, unselectedColorDarkTheme);
const selectedColor = useColorModeValue(selectedColorLightTheme, selectedColorDarkTheme);

...

<Tab color={unselectedColor} _selected={{ color: selectedColor }}>
```

To make this more reusable you can create a [custom Tab component](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/tabs#creating-custom-tab-components)

```
const CustomTab = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const tabProps = useTab({ ...props, ref })
    const styles = useMultiStyleConfig('Tabs', tabProps);

    const unselectedColor = useColorModeValue(unselectedColorLightTheme, unselectedColorDarkTheme);
    const selectedColor = useColorModeValue(selectedColorLightTheme, selectedColorDarkTheme);

    // If "__css" doesn't work, use "sx"
    return <Button {...tabProps} __css={styles.tab} color={unselectedColor} _selected={{ color: selectedColor }} />
}
```

**Option 2: [Customizing single components](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#customizing-single-components)**

```
const theme = extendTheme({
    components: {
        Tabs: {
            baseStyle: (props) => ({
                tab: {
                    color: mode(unselectedColorLightTheme, unselectedColorDarkTheme)(props);
                    _selected: {
                        color: mode(selectedColorLightTheme, selectedColorDarkTheme)(props);
                    }
                },
                // Apart from "tab", you can also customize "tabpanels", "tabpanel", and "tablist"
            }),
            ...
        }
    }
})
```

Then you can use this normally like this:

```
<Tabs>
  <TabList>
    <Tab>One</Tab>
    <Tab>Two</Tab>
  </TabList>
  <TabPanels>
    <TabPanel>1</TabPanel>
    <TabPanel>2</TabPanel>
  </TabPanels>
</Tabs>
```

---

[`useColorModeValue`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/color-mode#usecolormodevalue) - change color based on color mode

[`_selected`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props#pseudo)

`mode` - similar to `useColorModeValue`. Couldn't find the docs for this, but here's a [usage example](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/global-styles#default-styles)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was updated recently, but you can just use the color prop on the tab and that should do the trick.

Example:

```
    <Tab color='gray.200' >Hello</Tab>
```